# View row with key oracle.jbo.key[300100120394155] is not found in SrCategoryParentIterator

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a tree table with each parent node may have child nodes.
When we are Searching for child node directly. It gives this JBO exception.

View row with key oracle.jbo.key[300100120394155] is not found in    SrCategoryParentIterator

In PageDef, Range Size is defined as '16'. If I changed it to '-1' and add maxFetchSize='10000' to VO. 
This issue got resolved.

But Changing Range Size to '-1' reduces Performance and Scalability.

Do anybody know another efficient way to encounter this issue?
Or Root cause of this issue.

Any input would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this here in hope it will help someone in the future.

I was having almost the same exception.

**Exception stack**:

```
oracle.jbo.RowAlreadyDeletedException: JBO-25019: Entity row with key oracle.jbo.Key[2520 ] is not found in .
at oracle.jbo.server.OracleSQLBuilderImpl.doEntitySelectForAltKey(OracleSQLBuilderImpl.java:881)
at oracle.jbo.server.BaseSQLBuilderImpl.doEntitySelect(BaseSQLBuilderImpl.java:566)
at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.doSelect(EntityImpl.java:8836)
at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.populate(EntityImpl.java:7451)
at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.merge(EntityImpl.java:7790)
```

**Solution**

This exception was thrown due to the fact that there was an association of two tables and I was not adding it in the Query of the View.